# Java getInputStream Read not Exiting

Tags: java, serversocket

Hi I have created a server socket for reading byte array from socket using getInputStream,   But getInputStream.read is not exiting after endof data reaches. Below is my code.

```
 class imageReciver extends Thread {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    InputStream in;

    public imageReciver(int port) throws IOException
   {
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
   }


    public void run()
   {
     Socket server = null;
     server = serverSocket.accept();
     in = server.getInputStream();

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];

    while(true){
    int s = 0;
    s = in.read(buffer); //Not exiting from here
    if(s<0) break;
    baos.write(buffer, 0, s);
    }
    server.close();     
    return;
  } 
 }
```

From the client if I sent 2048 bytes, the line  `in.read(buffer)` should return -1 after reading two times, but it waiting there to read for the third time. How can I solve this ?
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server will need to close the connection, basically. If you're trying to send multiple "messages" over the same connection, you'll need some way to indicate the size/end of a message - e.g. length-prefixing or using a message delimiter. Remember that you're using a *stream* protocol - the abstraction is just that this is a stream of data; it's up to you to break it up as you see fit.

See the "network packets" in [Marc Gravell's IO blog post](http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/how-many-ways-can-you-mess-up-io.html) for more information.

EDIT: Now that we know that you have an expected length, you probably want something like this:

```
int remainingBytes = expectedBytes;
while (remainingBytes > 0) {
    int bytesRead = in.read(buffer, 0, Math.min(buffer.length, remainingBytes));
    if (bytesRead < 0) {
        throw new IOException("Unexpected end of data");
    }
    baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    remainingBytes -= bytesRead;
}
```

Note that this will also avoid *overreading*, i.e. if the server starts sending the next bit of data, we won't read into that.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply...Basically what I am doing is, the client(C++) sending image data which is uchar array and Java server receives its and convert to byte array. I know what will be the data length I am going to receive. Then how can I resolves the issue, just break the loop when data ends ?

Comment: @Haris: Keep track of how much data you've read, and break out of the loop when you've read as much as you expect. See my edited answer for details.

Comment: Hi thanks...I will do as you suggest...One more question, suppose if i don't know the data length then how can I manage this situation.

Comment: @Haris: Then as I suggested, you either need a delimiter, or a length-prefix, or you need to close the connection after writing the data.

Answer (score 1):

> If I send 2048 bytes, the line 'in.read(buffer)' should return -1 after reading two times.

You are mistaken on at least two counts here. If you send 2048 bytes, the line 'in.read(buffer)' should execute an *indeterminate* number of times, to read a total of 2048 bytes, *and then block.* It should only return -1 when the peer has closed the connection.